# How can I start a loop at a specific number?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

First off, I'd like to thank Jeremy for his help.

I have a set of add-on products that go along with my primary product. The options are a radio group.

I am using [Multi-Add](https://github.com/engram-design/MultiAdd) to tie everything together - and it's all working great. I'm able to add the primary and optional products to the cart.

Where I am hung up is, because I have a radio group - no matter which option I choose, I am always ending up with the *last* option being chosen. 
Which makes perfect sense since that's the last radio in the group that gets picked up.

Here is what I have so far:

```
...
// items[1][qty] is a <select> input for the primary product
...

{% for foo in products %}
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="items[2][qty]" value="1">
               {{ foo.title }} &ndash; {% if foo.defaultVariant.price == 0 %} Included with registration {% else %} {{ foo.defaultVariant.price|currency(cart.currency) }}{% endif %}
        </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="items[2][purchasableId]" value="{{ foo.defaultVariant.purchasableId }}">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see whatever the *last* radio input is, will be the value that is picked up by Craft regardless of what the user has actually chosen.

So I thought since each radio is a product (with no variants), I could just use the loop index:

```
<input type="hidden" name="items[{{ loop.index }}][purchasableId]" value="{{ foo.defaultVariant.purchasableId }}">
```

Which works, but the loop will start at `1` each time. I am hung up on how I can start the loop at a specific number. Or, perhaps there is a better way?

If I were using checkboxes, I'd only have one option per product/input name.

I have also tried using a `<select>` element, but I get hung up on how I can offer a "No thanks" option.

```
<select name="items[2][purchasableId]" class="form-control required">
    <option value="">Select</option>
     {% for foo in products %}
         <option value="{{ foo.defaultVariant.purchasableId }}">
         {{ foo.title }} &ndash; {% if foo.defaultVariant.price == 0 %} Included with registration {% else %} {{ foo.defaultVariant.price|currency(cart.currency) }}{% endif %}
         </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="items[2][qty]" value="1">
```

Which also works well, but if the user does not choose an option, because I am passing a value of `1` with the hidden input, I get an error that I am attempting to use an invalid purchasable ID. Which also makes perfect sense.

I feel like I am so close, but just can't quite see clear enough to know what to do. Worst case I suppose I just listen for either a change/click event via javascript and update the qty value accordingly.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't need JS here.

I'm  a bit pushed for time, so this won't be an epic answer, but e.g. with your select, you should not be using a hidden field for the qty.

The select itself just sets the quantity value - either `1` if the option is chosen or no value if the option is not chosen....it really is as simple as:

```
<form>

  {# primary item - use whatever input you like for qty, or just do it in a hidden... #}
  <input type="hidden" name="items[9999][purchasableId" value="{{ mainproduct.purchasableId }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="items[9999][qty]" value="1">

  {# accessories #}
  {% for accessory in accessories %}
    <input type="hidden" name="items[loop.index][puchasableId]" value=="{{ accessory.purchasableId }}"
    <select name="items[loop.index][qty]">
      <option value="1">Yes Please</option>
      <option value="0">No Thanks</option>
    </select> 
  {% endfor %}

</form>
```

This will cause the following to be posted - 
`items[0][purchasableId] = 45`

and depending on the user choice, either

`items[0][qty] = 1` or `items[0][qty] = 0`

...and multiAdd will just ignore this if the `qty` = `0`.

The key thing to understand is the value of the index is totally irrelevant as long as it is the same for the purchasableId and the qty - it just acts to join the data together - you could literally send:

```
items['TrumpIsInsane'][purchasableId] = 45
items['TrumpIsInsane'][qty] = 1
```

...and it should still work.  So for the primary product I just use something like `9999` so that I am sure it won't conflict with any of the loop indexes (I'm not going to have 10000 accessories eh?) -> it's just a made up number.

For completeness, radios would only be slightly different:

```
<form>

  {# primary item - use whatever input you like for qty, or just do it in a hidden... #}
  <input type="hidden" name="items[9999][purchasableId" value="{{ mainproduct.purchasableId }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="items[9999][qty]" value="1">

  {# accessories #}
  {% for accessory in accessories %}
    <input type="hidden" name="items[loop.index][puchasableId]" value=="{{ accessory.purchasableId }}"
    <input type="radio" name="items[loop.index][qty]" value="1" checked> Yes Please<br>
    <input type="radio" name="items[loop.index][qty]" value=""> No Thanks<br>
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```